# Cordova Camera permission missing in Manifest file

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, mobile, phonegap-build

I have a cordova app using version 6.4.0. I am building using phone gap build service by uploading zip file.

I have following permissions defined in config file:

```
<platform name="android">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</platform>
```

After build, Android manifest file is missing Camera permission. Rest of the permissions are added to manifest file.

Is Camera permission required in manifest file or other permissions shown above are sufficient for camera permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to edit your `config.xml` file at all for this, nor for using any other plugin for the matter.

**When installing the Camera plugin and during build time**, Cordova will automatically edit your AndroidManifest based on [the plugin's plugin.xml](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/plugin.xml) file settings to add all required permissions for you.

And do NOT edit a plugin's XML file either unless you are absolutely sure what you are doing, 99% of the time those files shouldn't be tweaked.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in config.xml
for the camera access, u need this only.remove all other permissions

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="2.4.1" />

  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" spec="1.4.1" >
    <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="App would like to access the camera." />

    <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="App would like to access the library." />
  </plugin>
```